# get the sum of DISTINCT values in SQL and show it in a record

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a SQL table,

```
 Card_A    | Card_B        | power 
-----------+---------------+-------
 3         | 1             |     9
 2         | 3             |     9
 2         | 3             |     4
```

I want to `sum(power)` with DISTINCT value of `Card_A` and `Card_B`. When `Card_A = 2` and `Card_B = 3` , there are two identical power values, 9 and 4 respectively. Output should be,

```
 Card_A    | Card_B        | power 
-----------+---------------+-------
 3         | 1             |     9
 2         | 3             |     13
```

This SQL query, I tried,

```
SELECT DISTINCT card_A, card_B, sum(power) FROM foo ;
```

I am using POstgresql. MySQL solution will be accepted too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT:

```
SELECT card_a, card_b, SUM(power)
FROM foo
GROUP BY card_a, card_b;
```

This should give you the result you're after.

A DISTINCT will find you the unique records in the result set, but it won't quite SUM up values correctly.

Using GROUP BY will create groups of the columns you specify (in this case, card_a and card_b), and the SUM will be calculated for each of those groups.